# PHP: sort array ouput but randomize same values

Tags: php, arrays

Whats the best/easiest way to get this:

what i have:

```
array('100', '100', '100', '80', '70', '70', '50', '45');
```

what the output should look like:

```
100 (random order)
100 (random order)
100 (random order)
80
70 (random order)
70 (random order)
50
45
```

Comment: What's the point of randomly outputting the same values?

Comment: the values also include data like a name and image and this people should be randomized by its value and DESC order if they dont have the same value

Comment: Does it matter which `70` comes first if they are the same value?

Comment: as its a ranking system and they have the same value noone of them should be favored

Answer (score 4):

you have to use usort or uasort (uasort keeps keys of the array). Using PHP 5.3, you may do it like this :

```
shuffle($array); // randomize

uasort($array, function($a, $b){
    if($a === $b) {
        return rand(0, 1);
    }
    return $a < $b;
});
```

You may have to name the function before, like the php documentation shows http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.uasort.php

Comment: this sound good... i tried it but the output is not as i excepted: theres no random right now and the sorting is like: 100,100,45,70,70

Comment: Yeah you need a shuffle() on the array before using uasort, forgot it sorry :)

Comment: One user defined sort function is enough but you have to return -1, 0 or 1 instead of 0 or 1 for the same and a boolean for differnt!. Try this:
            ```usort($this->_ads, function ($a, $d) {
                if ($a == $b) {
                    return mt_rand(0, 2) - 1;
                }
                return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
            });```

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or uksort depending on your requirements. You can then choose to randomly return a positive or negative number if the values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
http://codepad.org/SzSeUM4u

Based on the aasort from:
[Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: thanks but the output now is somehow completely random.. no grouped same values no values ordered by DESC

Comment: My answer is meant for multidimensional arrays.